# How do I get vue router to correctly push object to URL query string, not as "[Object Object]"?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, coffeescript, vue-router

I have spent days trying to figure this out, and am stumped. Specifically, I am speaking about the `filters` key, it keep showing as `filters=%5Bobject%20Object%5D`.

Here is example of my current, undesired, query string:

```
?items_page=1&items_per_page=50&sort_by=created_at&sort_dir=desc&filters=%5Bobject%20Object%5D
```

My goal is for the query string to be displayed using the same concept as this example:

```
?filters[event.since][0][type]=eq&filters[event.since][0][value]=all&filters[error.status][0][type]=eq&filters[error.status][0][value]=closed&sort=last_seen
```

This is my code snippet from before I make my axios call:

```
      @$router.push
        query:
          items_page: page
          items_per_page: @itemsPerPage
          sort_by: @sortBy
          sort_dir: @sortDir
          filters: @filtersComputed
```

My `@filtersComputed` I grabbed from VueDevTools is: `{"auction_id":["1","2"],"consignor_id":["20418"]}`

#### Things I have tried:

1. Using `JSON.stringify(@filtersComputed)` - although this is helpful it's not how the Vue Router [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-push-location-oncomplete-onabort) do it and I ran into problems.

I am on vue-router 3.0.6, and vue 2.5.17. Please let me know if there is any other supporting information and I will provide.

## EDIT 1:

@skirtle mentioned that my example was not relative to my actual data, so here's the query string I am aiming to obtain something like the following. I'm not picky, I just need to be able to see the data in the URL so that people can share search results with each other:

```
?items_page=1&items_per_page=50&sort_by=created_at&sort_dir=desc&filters[auction_id]=1&filters[auction_id]=2&filters[consignor_id]=20418
```

## EDIT 2:

This is what the query string looks like if I use `JSON.stringify(@filtersComputed)`:

```
?items_page=1&items_per_page=50&sort_by=created_at&sort_dir=desc&filters=%7B%22auction_id%22%3A%5B%221%22,%222%22%5D,%22consignor_id%22%3A%5B%2220418%22%5D%7D
```

Comment: It may help to clarify the requirements if your example query string used the same values as your example data for `@filtersComputed`.

Comment: @skirtle ok, I added an EDIT. good suggestion, thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the problems were with using `JSON.stringify`? That would seem like the simplest solution to me.

Comment: @skirtle I'm on a different branch right now so I will switch to it and share in another EDIT. But, I think the problem was it was url encoded instead of looking clean and "human readable".

Comment: @skirtle ok I added EDIT 2.

Comment: In that case I think you're probably going to have to specify `parseQuery` and `stringifyQuery` to get what you want: https://router.vuejs.org/api/#parsequery-stringifyquery. Either that or equivalent encoding/decoding within the relevant components, which seems less clean. Either way the human-readability requirement makes a simple task really quite complicated. I suggest trying to find a library that can encode/decode this format for you, otherwise there's a lot of fiddly code needs writing.

Comment: @skirtle ok thank you! I was thinking I was doing something wrong. Instead of passing the entire stringified object, I am going to try and list each property separately to avoid the url encoding of curly braces etc. If I do it separately, I get something like `?items_page=1&items_per_page=50&sort_by=created_at&sort_dir=desc&auction_ids=1&auction_ids=2&artist_name`